# Why is my paragraph not showing when I type in wrong email format in the input field?

Tags: javascript, frontend

Why is my paragraph (the warning message supposed to be shown below the input field when someone not correctly type in their email address) not showing?

Thank you.

[image: final look]

```js
function validateEmail(email) {
  const re = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$/;

  return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
}
```

```css
form .error {
  border-color: var(--Light-Red);
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

form .error_text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 73.5rem;
  font-size: .95rem;
  margin-top: 0.8rem;
  color: hsl(354, 100%, 66%);
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: italic;
}

.error_text {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form id="form" class="form">
  <input type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Your Email Address" id="email" name="email" required/>
  <button id="button" type="submit">Notify Me</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I don't see any `p` elements provided, nor do I see anything that attempts to show or hide elements based on that validation method. Are you missing some code here?

Comment: Please see [ask] for tips on making your problem more clear, then update your post. At a minimum it should include the paragraph you mention and any code required to see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have provided a very big value to the `top` property of `.error_text` class. That's why it's going way out of the window and you can't see it. Try changing the value to `top: 0` or something smaller.

Comment: hi yes thank you ,I saw my message now!! But I couldn't position it right under the input field..

Comment: @Reno for that you'd have to play around with css and see if a lower value or higher value works for you. I can't exactly give the correct value because you're using `rem` so it depends on your root's value.

Comment: hi I removed the position property and adjusted the top ,now its right under the input filed:) Thank you again